# Login when using OpenID for First Party authentication

Tags: security, microservices, openid-connect, openid, openiddict

I'm building a few 1st party microservices with requirements that led me to being interested in using OpenID/OAuth for all my first party communication. The requirements are as following:

- 2 resource servers.
- 1 website with access to both resource servers
  from the client(NextJS - SSR enabled ReactJS SPA).
- 1 automation microservice having full access to both resource servers using client credentials.

With these requirements I thought it would be best if I utilised OpenID for every first party connection as well. That means that when I login (via the SPA -> API) I immedietely use the authorization code workflow to get an auth code that I then send into a NextJS API Route to verify and then I store the refresh token and access token on the client-side. My question is is this a sound strategy and if it is, what is the best way to authenticate the /connect/authorize request after the API login request? Would it be to...

1. ...use a temporary(expiry time 30 seconds) cookie?
2. ...use some kind of temporary one-time use code?
3. ...some other better solution that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 0):

For new projects I would recommend that you consider storing the tokens only in the backend and not in the browser. It is better to only use classic session cookies between the browser and the backend.

Do check out this video for more details: [alert‘OAuth 2 0’; // The impact of XSS on OAuth 2 0 in SPAs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lEnbi4KClVw&ab_channel=PhilippeDeRyck)

This is another good resource: [The BFF Pattern (Backend for Frontend): An Introduction](https://blog.bitsrc.io/bff-pattern-backend-for-frontend-an-introduction-e4fa965128bf)